# How to create bottom border top-left and top-right radius?

Tags: css

I have a tab menu in my project, which active menu needs a bottom border with top-left and top-right radius. See the image bellow-
[image: tab menu]

Comment: show your code please

Comment: can you please explain. i can help you

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for your interest. @Dream Hunter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this. Representative example below. Using pseudo element `:after` for `active` menu element. I use `border-bottom` for `.menu .item` and not for `.menu` so to change it for `active` state.

You can adjust precise values.

#### Snippet

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu .item {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu .item.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.menu .item.active:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  height: 13px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="item active">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

border-radius: valueOfLeftTop valueOfRightTop ValueOfRightBottom ValueOfLeftBottom;

e.g. border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0 ;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in menu css

```
menu{
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```